# Problems with rigging and bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Trying to rig a hat so the tail of the hat moves a little but the base does not.
Followed a few rigging tutorials and it worked on a simple baton shape but not on this hat.
I modelled the hat from scratch. So when I move bones it creates strange shapes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should rework the weight painting. Maybe using a gradient so that the base of the hat has no weight.

Comment: also maybe segment each bone, choose B-Bones display then go into Properties panel > Bone > Bendy Bones and increase the Segments value, it will round the shape